\newpage not active with \twocolumn
I want to put the text on a newpage, but cannot do so with a call to \newpage when using \twocolumn.  What is happening ?
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

Arriva un momento nella vita in cui bisogna attingere alla propria forza
interiore per prendere una decisione risoluta, agire e cambiare
direzione.  Questa è una scelta che si oppone sia al male attivo sia al
male dell'inazione.  In quell'ambiente buio e spietato, la linea di
demarcazione tra il bene e il male che attraversa il cuore di ogni
individuo era una costante realtà quotidiana da affrontare.  L'era senza
legge e le promesse vuote di meritocrazia del Primo Ministro Joseph
Muscat, insieme a Konrad Mizzi, Edward Scicluna, Christopher Fearn e
altri, rivelavano una totale assenza di civiltà.  Senza legge, non può
esserci civiltà, e io non ne trovai alcuna.  Questo e precisamente il
mio punto: riconoscendo il vuoto di civiltà, vedo l'opportunità di
introdurla.  Le ricordo che, qualora lei scelga di rispondere,

\newpage
\newpage

Arriva un momento nella vita in cui bisogna attingere alla propria forza
interiore per prendere una decisione risoluta, agire e cambiare
direzione.  Questa è una scelta che si oppone sia al male attivo sia al
male dell'inazione.  In quell'ambiente buio e spietato, la linea di
demarcazione tra il bene e il male che attraversa il cuore di ogni
individuo era una costante realtà quotidiana da affrontare.  L'era senza
legge e le promesse vuote di meritocrazia del Primo Ministro Joseph
Muscat, insieme a Konrad Mizzi, Edward Scicluna, Christopher Fearn e
altri, rivelavano una totale assenza di civiltà.  Senza legge, non può
esserci civiltà, e io non ne trovai alcuna.  Questo e precisamente il
mio punto: riconoscendo il vuoto di civiltà, vedo l'opportunità di
introdurla.  Le ricordo che, qualora lei scelga di rispondere,

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE.

Off-topic: Unless you find there's nothing wrong with hyphenating the name "Joseph" as "Jose-ph", you may want to add the instruction \babelhyphenation[italian]{jo-seph} to the preamble of your document. :-)

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)
To quote @FrankMittelbach from his answer to the posting Is it wrong to use \clearpage instead of \newpage?:

A second difference [between \newpage and \clearpage] is that \clearpage actually always starts a new “page”, while \newpage really only ends the current column – and that is a big difference in twocolumn mode.

Hence, if you must force a page break while in twocolumn mode, be sure to issue the instruction \clearpage, not \newpage.

In two column mode \newpage mean new column in the same page or in the next page, and blank columns are ignored, just as blank pages are ignored in  one column mode, so:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
foo \newpage\newpage\newpage\newpage bar 
\end{document}

Is just a document of two pages, not five.
If what you are trying is leave a blank column (or page), use ~, or \mbox{} or \leavevmode   or \emph{}, or whatever without text but able to mark the page as "not blank".
Note many commands with or without arguments are not able to do that, so although \emph{foo} is equivalent to {\em foo}, \emph{} is not equivalent to {\em} at this respect, so the next document make only three pages, not four:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
foo  \newpage \emph{} \newpage {\em} \newpage bar 
\end{document} 

Or as Mico stated while editing this anwer, you can use simply   \clearpage that always mean what is says, but not only that. Note that this mean also flushing out all accumulated floats, so the result could be different. Consider this example:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t] \caption{foo} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t] \caption{foo} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t] \caption{foo} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t] \caption{foo} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t] \caption{foo} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t] \caption{foo} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t] \caption{foo} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t] \caption{foo} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t] \caption{foo} \end{figure}
\newpage
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage ~ % vs \clearpage
\end{document} 

This will print only two floats in the right column with \newpage but six with \clearpage.

I have two letters written in one document that uses \twocolumn.  Because I want to print the document and send the two letters separately, I need the second letter to show on a new page, not a new column on the same page.
